# Doing a put in progress callback

Tags: redux-saga

I am using a library that offers a `.progress` callback. It does a fetch and on progress it triggers this callback. I am doing it like this:

```
    const res = yield call(function fetchDownload() {
        return RNFetchBlob.config({ fileCache:true }).fetch('GET', url)
        .progress(function* progressDownload(received, total) {
            console.log(`progressed received: "${received}" total: "${total}"`);
            yield put(update(url, { progress:received/total }));
        });
    });
```

However the `progressDownload` callback never triggers. If I remove the superstar from `function* progressDownload` it then triggers and I see the console.log, however the `put` has no effect.

I am using RNFetchBlob, a React Native lib, here is the docs on its `progress` callbacker - https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/#user-content-uploaddownload-progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function* progressDownload() {...}` is a generator function, not a plain function.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A

And `fn` in `.progress(fn)` should be a plain function. So generator function is not called. If you want to put progress value to redux, you can use the channel api in redux-saga.

Like below

```
import {channel} from 'redux-saga';
import {/*... effects */} from 'redux-saga/effects;

//....

const progressChan = yield call(channel);
const putProgressToChannel = (received, total) => progressChan.put({received, total});

yield fork(updateProgressSaga, progressChan)

...blahblah.progress(putProgressToCahnnel);

//....

function* updateProgressSaga(progressChan) {
    while(true) {
        const {received, total} = take(progressChan);
        put(....);
    }
}
```

See more https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html

Comment: Interesting thanks very much Lee for this answer. I will try to understand and implement.

Comment: Lee, doesnt the `channel` here only take the latest 10 messages, how can I do a `channel` with no limit?

Comment: I think your saga doesn't  take the progress messages in channel.

By default, the channel buffers only 10 messages. (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#channelbuffer)
  
And you can set another buffer. (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#buffers)

Comment: Thanks @lee - how come you did `yield call(channel)` instead of just `channel()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here was my solution thanks to @Lee:

```
const url = 'blah.com';

const progressChan = channel();
const progressTask = yield fork(
    function*() {
        while (true) {
            const { percent } = take(progressChan);
            yield put(update(url, { progress:percent }));
        }
    }
);

const res = yield call(
    RNFetchBlob.config({ fileCache:true }).fetch('GET', url)
    .progress((received, total) => progressChan.put({ type:'PROGRESS', percent:received/total })
);

yield cancel(progressTask);

yield put(setProgress(100));
```